# Configure network for Firewall server

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking

I'm doing a big mess, maybe is a concept understanding of how network works, but here's my problem.

I've to make a setup to a CentOS server as a Firewall and Squid (already configured) to substitute a Windows gateway, and new server have 2 NICs with the following NIC and routing configuration:

**NIC eno1/IP 200 will be my output to Internet;
**NIC ifcfg-enp0s20f0/IP 210 will receive my internal traffic;
**IP 14 is my actual gateway server to be substuted.

## ip route list

default via 192.168.1.200 dev ifcfg-enp0s20f0  proto static  metric 100

default via 192.168.1.14 dev eno1  proto static  metric 101

192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.200  metric 100

192.168.1.0/24 dev ifcfg-enp0s20f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.210  metric 101

192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1

By some reason I don't understand why:

- With this configuration, I can't even ping google.com;
- If I add deault gateway as "route add default gw 192.168.1.14", the ping from my server works;
- How to change the Metric value;
- From a Windows machine, with route changed from gw IP 14 to IP 200/210, I can't reach the Internet.

If I'm not clear please tell me, and thank you so much for answers.

B.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer!

- Added GATEWAY=192.168.1.14 in my Internet NIC (IP 200);
- Removed GATEWAY line from my internal NIC (IP 210);

At this point, my internal IP 210 was getting a default gateway by itself; it was set in /etc/sysconfig/network, so I removed GATEWAY from this file and my routing was:

# ip route list

default via 192.168.1.14 dev eno1  proto static  metric 100

192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.200  metric 100

192.168.1.0/24 dev ifcfg-enp0s20f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.210  metric 101

192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1

Done! Thank you!

B.